# qemu virtio-blk strange restrictions

Tags: kernel, qemu

I'm trying to write a bare-bones OS targeting qemu with a virtio disk.

To begin with, all I want to do is read a sector from my raw disk. I set up a virtq with one entry doing the read from the disk, listed it in avail and poked the notify slot, but it said "virtio-blk missing headers". Looking in the source code, this turned out to mean that either there were no write descriptors or there were no read descriptors. Well I only want a read (i.e. device-write) descriptor but I reluctantly made the other, but still it barfed unless I chained them together, which is also visible in the source. At this point I set the size of the write to zero but then it explicitly barfed about it being zero.

I really don't want to do a write to the disk and I don't know why it's twisting my arm into doing so. Does anybody know how to ask qemu's virtio-blk to really, honestly just do a read?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The header needs to be device-readable, that place where the data's gonna land needs to be device-writable, and the status byte needs to be device-writable. That's why there must be at least one of each and why they must come in that order. Sensible coding suggests that the bit in the middle be a third descriptor so it can serve both disk-read and disk-write scenarios.

Comment: You are some hero! https://brennan.io/2020/03/22/sos-block-device/

Comment: This is also quite well documented here: https://web.eecs.utk.edu/~smarz1/courses/cosc361/notes/virtio/

Comment: Ouch - and now we mention it - here: https://wiki.osdev.org/Virtio